# Por que a função leValidaTexto retorna lixo?

Tags: c, funções

> Estou tentando validar a placa do carro, mas não estou conseguindo. Tentei usar o scanf no lugar do fgets e nada. Tô meio sem ideia do que pode estar ocasionando o problema.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>



/* 
Lucas Correia Barros
Síntese
Objetivo: Cadastrar carros de um colecionador
Entrada: Placa do carro e valor de aquisição
Saída: Carro cadastrado (C), listagem(L) dos carros cadastrados ate o momento, que contenham na placa as tres primeiras
letras da placa especificada, e encerramento(E), mensagem caso seja tentado o cadastramento de carros acima do máximo
permitido (Cadastro cheio)
 */

#define MAX_CARROS 200
#define MAX_PLACA 7
#define MIN_PLACA 7
#define MAX_VALOR 999999

//Le e valida opcao
char opcaoDesejada();
//Le e valida placa
void leValidaTexto(int valorMin, int valorMax, char texto[]);
int verificaPlaca(char placa[]);
char validaPlacaRepetido(int contadorCarros,char placas[][MAX_PLACA],char placa[]);


int main(){

    char opcao, placas[MAX_CARROS][MAX_PLACA]={0}, placa[MAX_PLACA]={0};
    float valor_aquisicao[MAX_CARROS];
    int contadorCarros=0, placaFlag=0, repetido=0;




    do{
        opcao = opcaoDesejada();
        system("cls");
        switch(opcao){
            case 'c':
                if(contadorCarros > MAX_CARROS){
                    printf("CADASTRO CHEIO!");
                }
                else
                    {
                        printf("Veiculo n%c %d\n", 167, contadorCarros+1);


                        leValidaTexto(MIN_PLACA, MAX_PLACA, placa);
                        printf("%s", leValidaTexto);
                        placaFlag = verificaPlaca(placa);


                        do{

                        repetido=validaPlacaRepetido(contadorCarros,placas,placa);

                        if((repetido)== 1 || (placaFlag==0)){
                            printf(" Placa ja existe \n");

                        }else{
                            strcpy(placas[contadorCarros],placa);
                        }

                        }while((repetido)== 1 || (placaFlag==0));

                        contadorCarros++;
                    }
        }


    }while(opcao != 'e');

    return 0;   
}

char opcaoDesejada(){

        char opcao;

        do{
            printf("\nCADASTRO DE AUTOMOVEIS\n\n");
            printf("C - CADASTRE UM CARRO\n");
            printf("L - LISTE OS CARROS CADASTRADOS\n");
            printf("E- ENCERRE O PROGRAMA\n");
            scanf(" %c", &opcao);
            opcao = tolower(opcao);
            if(opcao != 'c' && opcao != 'l' && opcao != 'e'){
                printf("\nOpcao desejada invalida. Tente novamente: ");
                }
        }while(opcao != 'c' && opcao != 'l' && opcao != 'e');

        return opcao;
    }

void leValidaTexto(int valorMin, int valorMax, char texto[]){

    do{
        printf("Digite a placa do veiculo:");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(texto, valorMax+1, stdin);

        if(texto[strlen(texto)-1] == '\n'){
            texto[strlen(texto)-1] = '\0';
        }

        if(strlen(texto)<valorMin || strlen(texto)<valorMax){
            printf("Placa invalida");
        }
    }while(strlen(texto)<valorMin || strlen(texto)<valorMax);
}

int verificaPlaca(char placa[]){

    int cont,flag=1;

    for(cont=0;cont<7;cont++){

      if(cont<3){
        if(!isalpha(placa[cont])){
            flag=0;
            break;

        }
    }else
        if(!isdigit(placa[cont])){
        flag=0;
        break;      
        }

    }
    return flag;
}

char validaPlacaRepetido(int contadorCarros,char placas[][MAX_PLACA],char placa[]){
    int repetido=0,cont;

    for(cont=0;cont<=contadorCarros;cont++){
        if(stricmp(placas[cont],placa)==0){
            repetido = 1;
            return repetido;

        }
    }
    return repetido;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código parece ainda estar em desenvolvimento e acredito que você ainda está aprendendo, do contrário poderia estar usando algo mais elaborado como *structs*, então acredito que você possui algumas limitações para fazer esse exercício.

Considerando isso, vou responder diretamente sua pergunta:

```
leValidaTexto(MIN_PLACA, MAX_PLACA, placa);
printf("%s", leValidaTexto);
```

Você está tentando imprimir a **função** leValidaTexto como se fosse uma string, e ela além de não retornar nada, não está sendo chamada no printf. No entanto, você envia a string *placa* para a função e é lá que a placa é armazenada, você logo na linha seguinte a este printf percebe isso porque usa a variável *placa*, ou seja, onde corretamente foi salvo a string que o usuário digita:

```
placaFlag = verificaPlaca(placa);
```

Portanto, basta ao invés de tentar imprimir a função como se fosse uma string, imprimir a variável *placa*:

```
leValidaTexto(MIN_PLACA, MAX_PLACA, placa);
printf("%s", placa);
```